# Exporting email chunks phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, phpmyadmin

I have read a lot about how to export data from phpmyadmin and I am familiar with the process, however I have encountered some issues in regards to exporting a very large email database.

I have a list of 40+ million emails that I need to export to a csv file.

So, what I am doing is specifying the amount of rows to dump:
(Dump some row(s)), and I'm exporting 1 million at a time.

Here's the part I am confused about:

Row to begin at:

For example, if I export 1,000,000 emails and start at row 0, then the next export should be another 1,000,000 emails but start at row 33,333.33?  Then the next export would be 1,000,000 emails starting at row 66,666.66.  Assuming that the default is 30 rows?

My goal is to have 40 csv files, each containing 1,000,000 emails.

If someone has a better idea of how to do this I'd love to hear your advice.

Thanks!

Comment: [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: if you export 1 million the next export starts at 1 million and 1

Comment: I have a total of 1,218,264 rows in my database.  Each row contains 30 emails.  So how can I start the second export at row 1,000,001?

Comment: You're not going to be able to offset by 33,333.33 since it's not possible to offset by a fraction of a row. You can use `LIMIT` to define the offset in your query `SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 33333, 33333` where the first number of the offset and the second is the number of rows to select. So the second query will use `LIMIT 66666, 33333`

Comment: That actually produces an error.  So that option does not work.

Comment: the count is rows NOT the number of emails you have in a row